# Localization at the left edge of a coherent left horn inclusion

Tags: ct.category-theory, simplicial-stuff

Let $\Lambda^n_0 \hookrightarrow \Delta^n$ be a left horn inclusion for $n>1$.  Then consider $\mathfrak{C}(\Lambda^n_0)\hookrightarrow \mathfrak{C}(\Delta^n)$, and we have a cofibration $[1]_{\Delta^0}\hookrightarrow \mathfrak{C}(\Lambda^n_0)$ induced by the inclusion $\{0,1\} \subseteq \Lambda^n_0$.

Let $I$ denote the simplicial category with two objects and such that all of its Hom-objects are equal to $\Delta^0$.

Then we can form the pushouts along $[1]_{\Delta^0}\to I$ to obtain the induced map

$\widetilde{\mathfrak{C}(\Lambda^n_0)} \hookrightarrow \widetilde{\mathfrak{C}(\Delta^n)}$.

This should be a Dwyer-Kan equivalence of simplicial categories, but I'm getting confused doing the computation.

What is this inclusion on the pairwise Hom spaces?

Comment: It looks like it forces Hom(1,n) in the localization to be Hom(0,n) in the original object, and so the map is the identity on objects and a cubical horn inclusion on Hom(0,n) and Hom(1,n), but i may be mistaken.